# How to access my model in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with this code. I'm running laravel 5.4.

The error: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/64ioxdf4mv6ps1w/Screenshot%202017-02-28%2020.11.33.png?dl=0

The Controller function:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Thread;


class ThreadController extends Controller
{

    public function show($id) {

        return Thread::where('id', '=', $id)->messages();
    }
}
```

The Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Thread extends Model
{
    public function messages()  
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Message::class)->get();
    }


}
```

Comment: Please add your error message/code in the body of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest adding your error code instead of linking to image (right now AWS is down, thus I'm unable to view the image).

Regardless, the `messages` method is defining a relationship and as such, is an instance of the query builder. Rather than chaining the `get` method there, I suggest a slightly different approach:

In your controller

```
public function show($id)
{
    // Use first() instead of get() since you're returning a
    // specific model by its primary key (I assume)
    return Thread::where('id', $id)->with('messages')->first();
}
```

And in your model

```
public function messages()
{
    // This returns a query builder instance, which is what you want.
    // It defines the relationship between Thread and Message
    return $this->hasMany(Message::class);
}
```

This will `eager load` your messages along with your `Thread` model.

Hope it helps!

Comment: So a follow up question if that's OK. $message = User::find(1)->messages->create($request->only('body')); gives me an error saying that create() does not exist. Any idea why? The User model has a messages function that returns a hasMany relationship...

Comment: @Joel You'll want to ask in a new question, as it's too much to answer here. The concept is this: don't chain the `create` method onto your query. You need to `get` the object using `firstOrFail` or similar, then you can use the `messages()` method to save a message.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Joel's question in the comments...

User::find(1)->messages->create($request->only('body'));

Is not calling the 'messages function' you mentioned and not returning the relationship. Instead, it is calling the messages **property**, which is something different.

Comment: A, true! But changing to messages() generates this error instead: 

`BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
Method create does not exist.`